# Ionic PWA app very slow when url enter at browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

When i click button (Already added "Add to Home screen") first time enter a site is very slow. it time will take 40 seconds. Any one suggest me how i increase my PWA site speed ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the main problem is your package size, you can try the tips mentioned here - https://julienrenaux.fr/2017/07/20/optimized-ionic-angular-css-bundle-for-pwas/

This helped me greatly reduce my package size and subsequently improve the load times for the PWA I built recently. Specifically by [building for one platform only](https://julienrenaux.fr/2017/07/20/optimized-ionic-angular-css-bundle-for-pwas/#Build_for_one_platform_only), and [removing the CSS that I wasn't using](https://julienrenaux.fr/2017/07/20/optimized-ionic-angular-css-bundle-for-pwas/#Build_for_one_platform_only). I'd recommend [removing ionicons](https://julienrenaux.fr/2017/07/20/optimized-ionic-angular-css-bundle-for-pwas/#Remove_ionicons) too if you aren't using them.

Also try and minimise the number of third party packages you are including in your app.

Of course this is assuming you are using Ionic 2/3 to build you PWA.